# Make gradient in dark mode `background-image` work with simple background `background-color` in light mode in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a `div` with class `bg-blue-100 text-blue-900 dark:bg-info` where `bg-info` is `linear-gradient(to right, hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.2), transparent 50%)`

I get the light mode working fine but `dark:bg-info` doesn't work as it uses `background-image` CSS property rather than `background-color` CSS property for light mode.

How do I make the dark mode work? There is a conflict between `background-image` in Dark Mode & `background-color` in Light Mode.

How to solve it?

I've made a Stackblitz demo showing the problem -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-6frqvs-tqnsnl?file=pages%2Findex.tsx

Open in New Window as Tailwind Dark Mode doesn't show side-by-side on Stackblitz.

Notice, how it doesn't show blue gradient on Dark Mode despite the code being:

```html
<div className="p-4 m-4 h-20 w-96 bg-red-400 text-red-900 dark:bg-info">Hello hi</div>
```

## Edit:

I've managed to make Dark Mode work on Tailwind Play so here's the demo -> https://play.tailwindcss.com/fecClyOaIZ

Check only the 1st box. 2nd box is a demonstration of how it must really look in Dark Mode.

In Dark Mode, the 1st box should look like dark blue with a black gradient (see 2nd box)

## Light Mode (1st box looks correct in light mode)

[image: light-mode]

## Dark Mode (1st box looks incorrect in dark mode. Should actually look like 2nd box)

[image: dark-mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `dark:bg-transparent` as CSS allows `background-color` & `background-image` at the same time.

```html
<div class="h-screen m-0 p-0 dark:bg-black">
  <div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center mx-20 text-center h-full">
    <div class="px-4 py-4 rounded-md bg-pink-100 text-pink-900 dark:bg-info dark:bg-transparent dark:text-white">This shouldn't look like this in Dark Mode</div>
    <button id="toggleDark" class="inline-flex justify-center px-4 py-2 text-sm font-medium mt-8 text-green-900 bg-green-100 border border-transparent rounded-md hover:bg-green-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-offset-2 focus-visible:ring-blue-500" onclick="document.documentElement.classList.toggle('dark');">Toggle Dark Mode</button>
    <div class="px-4 py-4 rounded-md dark:bg-info mt-8 dark:text-white">It should look like this in Dark Mode</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tailwind Play -> https://play.tailwindcss.com/ZWl7ZBwqnQ

[image: dark-mode]